# How to use Ajax POST with jQuery in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

This code works fine:

```
$('#loginForm').attr('method', 'POST');
$('#loginForm').attr('action', basePath + url);
```

then I want to add a callback for handlling responsed messages and have a more common function for submission of a form, so I write a function as below:

```
//------ another function ----
saveCookie();
var loginFormParam = {
    type: "POST",
    url: basePath + "/sys/security/login.do"
};
prepareForm("loginForm", loginFormParam, loginCallback);
//----- end of another function
```

then,

```
function prepareForm(whichForm, formAttr, callback) {
    $("#" + whichForm).submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: formAttr.type,
            url: formAttr.url,
            success: callback
        })
    })
}
```

But when the form submitted, I get a GET request not POST. I must misunderstand something but I don't know where.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling `prepareForm` and what is the type of the `formAttr` value?

Comment: Can you post a more complete version of the code you're using? How do you call that *prepareForm* function?

Comment: Thanks @Astaroth, you're right, I've added more code above.

Comment: I don't think the error is within the code you just posted. It seems that is somewhere else. When you say "I get a `GET` call" you mean ajax or that the form is submited with by GET? If it's that you need to stop the event propagation.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` is default method is GET [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Test if your `formAttr` contains a type and has the value of POST

Comment: that means formAttr is not set

Comment: thanks for your reply. Before I call the function `prepareForm` ,I made a `formAttr` which contains a `type` with `'POST'`, but I finally got a GET request.